# Bundler not working with rbenv, could not find [gem]

Tags: ruby, sinatra, bundler, rbenv

I've just made the switch from rvm to **rbenv** and I'm trying to use bundler for gem management. After running `bundle install` and trying to run a simple sinatra app (`ruby app.rb`), I get this:

```
Could not find haml-3.1.4 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Running `bundle install` again had no effect. Also tried `bundle update` as suggested by another question response.

This is my Gemfile:

```
source "http://rubygems.org"

gem "sinatra"
gem "haml"
```

This is what `bundle show` produces

```
* bundler (1.0.22)
* haml (3.1.4)
* rack (1.4.1)
* rack-protection (1.2.0)
* sinatra (1.3.2)
* tilt (1.3.3)
```

This is what my app requires:

```
require "rubygems"
require "bundler/setup"
require 'sinatra'
```

I'm convince that this is some kind of path issue where bundler and rbenv aren't playing along. I've tried looking through rbenv's documentation but was not able to find to anything.

*Note: In a different sinatra app I get the following when trying to run it:*

```
Could not find addressable-2.2.7 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

---

### Supplemental info

`echo $PATH`
`/Users/uri/.rbenv/shims:/Users/uri/.rbenv/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin`

`which bundle`
`/Users/uri/.rbenv/shims/bundle`

### Update

If I do `bundle install --system` it works. Although I can't see this as being a viable solution.

Comment: what is your `PATH`, and what is the output of `which bundle`?

Comment: I added this info to my original question.

Comment: Three years later... Same problem. This is just sad, the whole package/dependency management environment for ruby feels like a huge hack.

Answer (score 106):

I was having the same issue. One hint was that `rbenv exec bundle exec command` worked and that `rbenv exec bundle install --path vendor/bundle` worked, but their prefixed equivalents failed.

I wiped my `~/.rbenv`, `~/.gem` `Gemfile.lock` and `vendor/bundle` a few times trying to start fresh. Once these were cleaned away I tried the following:

```
rbenv install 1.9.3-p194
rbenv rehash # for paranoia's sake
rbenv global 1.9.3-p194
gem env # to check that everything was pointing at 1.9 and not the system
gem install --no-ri --no-rdoc bundler
rbenv rehash # necessary to load up the bundle executable
bundle --path=vendor/bundle
```

and it worked!

I think the important thing, since I tried this a few times, is to remove the .gem file from your home directory. It seems to get in the way.

Comment: You are my hero :) I think everything went haywire when I installed bundler before using rbenv to change to 1.9.3

Comment: You saved me mentioning ~/.gem, now bundle-install works well!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm pretty sure my problem was that I didn't run `rbenv rehash` after I installed Bundler again. After `gem install bundler && rbenv rehash && bundle install` while using an rbenv Ruby the error was gone!

Comment: I logged in to upvote you. This problem was beginning to drive me crazy. The command that seemed to do it was
`gem install --no-ri --no-rdoc bundler` and `rbenv rehash`

Comment: It's a contradiction with the gem path. I just had the same problem...my bundle install ran but a subsequent gem list didn't show them. I renamed my ~/.gem in .gem_old and now the second position in my apps gem_path is being used...and this one actually contains the necessary gems. I still don't quite understand the gem path thing...

Comment: `gem install --no-ri --no-rdoc bundler` was the missing trick for me.  Thanks!

Comment: `bundle --path=vendor/bundle` was all the magic I needed to get rake to work, apparently! Thanks :)

Answer (score 23):

Have you run

```
rbenv rehash
```

This will provide shims for all ruby binaries, including ones installed by gems.

Comment: +1 for `rbenv rehash`. You MUST execute this line after installing a new ruby with rbenv.

Answer (score 20):

Adding this

```rb
set :default_environment, {
  'PATH' => "$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
}
```

to deploy.rb worked for me.

http://henriksjokvist.net/archive/2012/2/deploying-with-rbenv-and-capistrano/

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you use the gem 'capistrano-rbenv' (https://github.com/yyuu/capistrano-rbenv )

1. make sure you have "rbenv" and a ruby version (e.g. 1.9.3) installed in remote server
2. in your config/deploy.rb (capistrano file)

   ```
   require 'capistrano-rbenv'
   ```
3. in your Gemfile:

   ```
   gem 'capistrano-rbenv', '1.0.1'
   ```
4. that's it. to debug if it works, just run:

   ```
   $ cap shell
   cap> which ruby
    ** [out :: 10.103.13.74] /root/.rbenv/shims/ruby
   cap> ruby -v
    ** [out :: 10.103.13.74] ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10 revision 37606) [x86_64-linux]
   ```

Comment: This resolved my bundle not found issue when deploying, although it was available while logged in directly to the box.

Answer (score 2):

You should try using [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby#readme). chruby is an ultra-minimal (~80 lines) alternative to RVM / rbenv. Unlike rbenv, chruby does not rely on shims and simply modifies `PATH`, `GEM_HOME` and `GEM_PATH`.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem when I switched from using rvm to rbenv. I found my bundler was showing a different list of gems than my `gem list` command. First check to see which paths your bundler and gem are using. For bundler use the `show` command and select any gem.

```
$ bundle show ffi
/my/project/path/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.1.5
```

and my `gem environment` command (in part)

```
$ gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.23
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2011-07-09 patchlevel 290) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/rolf/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
```

Here I could see my gem is pointing to the correct rbenv path but my bundler is pointing to my project's vendor path.

Running the following command should fix the bundler path problem:

```
$ bundle install --system
```

Bundler path should now be pointing to the rbenv path.

```
$ bundle show ffi
/Users/rolf/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.1.5
```

Also I found when I run the `rvm implode` command to uninstall rvm, there were still the following files which I needed to change to remove rvm paths:

```
~/.profile
~/.bashrc
~/.zshrc
```

If the `~/.rvm` path still exists, you will need to remove this.

You will need to open a new terminal session after changing these files. Finally after all that I finally got my bundler and gem in sync.

Answer (score 1):

Just a reminder too that rbenv is *not* compatible with rvm they do not play nicely. For your sanity, uninstall rvm if you want to use rbenv.  From the rbenv README:

> Compatibility note: rbenv is incompatible with rvm. Things will appear
>   to work until you try to install a gem. The problem is that rvm
>   actually overrides the gem command with a shell function! Please
>   remove any references to rvm before using rbenv.

Luckily, Wayne (rvm creator) provides a remove rvm easily using:

`rvm implode`

As a regular use or:

`rvmsudo rvm implode`

To clean rvm system wide.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the stuff here, but what did it for me was discovering that I had a .bundler in my user home directory for some reason. This was causing the weird problem above where the 'which' command correctly listed bundle in the shims path, but checking bundle -v showed the old system version, while /Users/jerimiah/.rbenv/shims/bundle showed the latest versions. I deleted .bundler in my home directory, rehashed, restarted my terminal, and everything started working.

Answer (score 0):

Give this rbenv plugin a try, it will make shims aware of the bundler paths

https://github.com/carsomyr/rbenv-bundler

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming across this issue. This is the easiest solution to the "Can't find gem bundle situation (>= 0.a)

Command:

```
gem update --system
```

Then update bundler command:

```
bundle update --bundler
```