# rbenv/bundler dependency hell

Tags: ruby, bundler, osx-mavericks, rbenv

In the process if trying to manage and update my ruby environment through rbenv on OS X Mavericks (upgrading from 2.0.0p45 to 2.1.1), I've got a bit of a mess in a preexisting project.

When I try to run cucumber, for example, I get

`localhost: cucumber
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in 'to_specs': Could not find 'cucumber' (>= 0) among 9 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:309:in 'to_spec'
    from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:53:in 'gem'
    from /usr/bin/cucumber:22:in '<main>'`

Running

```
gem environment
```

shows me

`- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.2.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.1.1 (2014-02-24 patchlevel 76) [x86_64-darwin13.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/bin/ruby`

But in in the gems folder inside /2.1.0, I only have:

`rake-10.1.0        rake-10.3.2     rdoc-4.1.0      test-unit-2.1.1.0`

Bundler is installing things into

`/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/ruby/2.0.0/gems/`

even with specified with `--path` to the precise directory given by `gem environment`.

How can I get the gems to install correctly so that cucumber works?

I tried `bundle exec cucumber` and got:

`Could not find rake-10.3.2 in any of the sources
Run 'bundle install' to install missing gems.`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely certain what was happening here, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13540813/802484) on a similar question did the trick. I suspect that bundler was not rehashed correctly to the different version of ruby shimmed in by rbenv.