# 'bundle install' with rbenv cause same error message many times

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, bundler, rbenv

On Mac OSX Yosemite, I've got following error many times with running 'bundle install'.

my process...

```
$ brew install rbenv
$ brew install ruby-build
$ rbenv install 2.1.2
$ rbenv rehash
$ bundle install
$ rbenv rehash
$ cd myrepos 
$ bundle install
```

ERROR!

```
Gem files will remain installed in /Users/user/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/debase-0.0.9 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/user/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.1.0-static/debase-0.0.9/gem_make.out
from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:38:in `block in build'
from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tempfile.rb:324:in `open'
```

...

```
from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:132:in `rescue in require'
from /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
from extconf.rb:24:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

Comment: Is there more to the error. It looks like you are missing some native libraries that are required to compile the debase gem

Comment: Thank you, @Doon.
I've self answered.
This issue may be related with [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602806/bundler-not-working-with-rbenv-could-not-find-gem/11146496#11146496)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `~/.gem` .

I've tryed following. However they do not have meaning for this issue.

- update xcode
- change gcc to clang
- re-install ruby

It seems that `~/.gem` causes errors with running bundle of rbenv.