# Why do I get the error "Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.2" although I have 2.2.2 installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rbenv

I'm using rbenv and I get the error `Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.2` when I run the `bundle install` command in my project. The strange thing is that I've actually got the 2.2.2 version installed (as my Gemfile specifies), and not the 2.0.0 version. (See image below).

[image]

I tried the solution offered in this thread: [Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23039528/your-ruby-version-is-2-0-0-but-your-gemfile-specified-2-1-0), but it had no effect.

I'm on an MacBook Air with Yosemite if that makes any difference.

Update:

- `which ruby` -> `Users/myuser/.rbenv/shims/ruby`
- `ruby -v` -> `ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-darwin14]`
- `rbenv global 2.2.2` and `rbenv rehash`, has no effect
- `which bundle` -> `/usr/bin/bundle`
- `gem env`-> - `GEM PATHS:`

  - `/Users/myuser/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0`
  - `/Users/myuser/.gem/ruby/2.2.0`

Comment: What actually says the command ```which ruby```?

Comment: what does `ruby -v` say? Maybe you might need `rbenv rehash`

Comment: Try 'rbenv global 2.2.2' then 'rbenv rehash'

Comment: `which ruby` -> `Users/myuser/.rbenv/shims/ruby` |
`ruby -v` -> `ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-darwin14]` |
`'rbenv global 2.2.2' then 'rbenv rehash'`, has no effect

Comment: what does `which bundle` say? I guess your bundle still points to the system one, and rbenv rehash doesn't pick it up properly

Comment: I'd guess something like that too. But I have no idea how to fix that problem. which bundle -> /usr/bin/bundle

Comment: I stumbled upon this thread recently. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69290792/1137814) is my solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally solved my problem using this thread [Bundler not working with rbenv, could not find [gem]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602806/bundler-not-working-with-rbenv-could-not-find-gem),

by using these commands after reinstalling rbenv:

- `gem install --no-ri --no-rdoc bundler`
- `rbenv rehash`
- `bundle --path=vendor/bundle`

Answer (score 26):

You have a system `bundler` installed, and rbenv is always trying to pick that up. [Based on the steps on this site](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/issues/576):

- Make sure you are using the proper gem version. Type `which gem` and `gem env` and check that it points to your 2.2.2 ruby version
- Install bundler using this gem: `gem install bundler`
- Once this version of bundler is installed run `rbenv rehash`
- Call `which bundler`, make sure it now points to the shim version of bundler

`gem install` might not work properly with `rbenv` if you have your `GEM_HOME` or `GEM_PATH` variable overriden, or if you have custom configs in `~/.gemrc`, `~/.gem/gemrc` or `/etc/gemrc`. Check the result of `gem env`, it should say something like this:

```
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/<youruser>/.rbenv/versions/<ruby-version>/lib/ruby/gems/<ruby-framework-version>
(...)
- GEM PATHS:
  - /Users/<youruser>/.rbenv/versions/<ruby-version>/lib/ruby/gems/<ruby-framework-version>
```

(note the `ruby-framework-version` doesn't always *exactly* match the `ruby-version`. If the `ruby-version` is the correct one then the path should be alright)

if not, make sure you don't have any environment overrides or custom configs inside the files mentioned above.

You might also want to try to remove all bundlers from your machine and try again afterwards:

- `rbenv local system`
- `gem uninstall bundler`
- `rbenv local 2.2.2`
- `gem uninstall bundler`

Comment: `gem env`-> - `GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/myuser/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
     - /Users/myuser/.gem/ruby/2.2.0`

could this be a part of the problem, or is it supposed to say 2.2.0?

Comment: @bork that's okay. Did you try to reinstall bundler and do the rest of the steps?

Comment: just did and I went through all the steps in your post. my bundler doesn't point to shim but to `/usr/bin/bundle`, according to `which bundler`. The paths seems to be as they should be.

Comment: Try reemoving both bundlers: `rbenv local system` `gem uninstall bundler` `rbenv local 2.2.2` `gem uninstall bundler`. Then try again

Comment: And don't be fooled by the "DEPRECATED - Never run `rbenv rehash` again" at https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-gem-rehash. These steps worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that I hadn't properly re-initialized rbenv after installing and switching to the new ruby version.

In my shell config I had an incorrect check to avoid executing `source (rbenv init -|psub)` if `rbenv` wasn't installed. After manually sourcing it worked again.