# bundle uses wrong ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle, rbenv

I'm trying to run

`env RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:migrate`

and get the following error

`Your Ruby version is 2.1.7, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.3`

`ruby -v`

gives me

`ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-darwin15]`

I'm using rbenv, if that matters. `rbenv versions` gives the following:

  `system
* 2.2.3 (set by /Users/thatsme/Projects/demoproject/.ruby-version)`

So I have no `ruby 2.1.7` installed. Spring is not running and I've run `rbenv rehash`. Then `bundler gem` is installed.
I'm going nuts on this. Can somebody please tell me why the wrong ruby version is being used? Thanks!

Comment: This link may have some options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23039528/your-ruby-version-is-2-0-0-but-your-gemfile-specified-2-1-0

Comment: Thanks for the link but it was not a missing bundler gem. I've updated my question accordingly.

Comment: I had the same issue yesterday - I [followed this articles steps](https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.11-el-capitan#ruby) to install ruby and I forgot to add rbenv to bast - notice the `# Add rbenv to bash so that it loads every time you open a terminal` comment in the article.

Comment: @MichalSzyndel as I wrote, `rbenv rehash` didn't solve the problem. @Vucko thanks for the hint. I'm struggling to make this work for fish shell.

Comment: what does `which bundle` tell you?

Comment: `/Users/nandersen/.rbenv/shims/bundle` @MichalSzyndel

Comment: `/Users/nandersen/.rbenv/shims/ruby` @MichalSzyndel

Comment: Can you make sure once again that your desired ruby version is activated in this directory in rbenv?

Comment: You mean via `rbenv local 2.2.3`?

Answer (score 17):

Running the command below helped me somehow:
`rbenv exec gem install bundler`

Comment: Oh wow. I've been searching all around on dozens of similar issues with solutions that haven't worked, and this finally fixed it for me. Thanks!

Comment: ```rbenv exec gem install bundler``` zsh: command not found: rbenv

Comment: for `asdf` user `asdf exec gem install bundler`. Seems to fix for me.

Answer (score 6):

Assumption: You are using RVM.
This means there's a ruby version installed outside of RVM.
Clear your rvm rubies by running

```
rvm uninstall <ruby version>
```

once you have uninstalled all rvm rubies do `ruby -v`, if this returns an output specifying a ruby version then thats the root of the problem. Uninstall it with

```
sudo apt-get remove ruby
```

Now install your rvm rubies with `rvm install <ruby version>` and set it as default `rvm use <ruby version>`

Now install bundler

```
gem install bundler
```

And do `bundle install`

Comment: Seems that just running "gem install bundler" (after updating ruby version, doint it with RVM isn't a prerequisite) solves the problem

Comment: This works for me, but why on earth would this make a difference in identifying the ruby to use?

Answer (score 5):

TLDR;

***Check really carefully the content of your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` file.***

None of the answers actually solve my problem. So here's my solution.

This is the error that I got:

```
$ bundle install
Your Ruby version is 3.0.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.1
```

I checked my `rbenv` setup:

```
$ rbenv versions
  system
  2.4.1
  2.5.0
  2.7.0
* 2.7.1 (set by /Users/setoelka/awesome-project/.ruby-version)
  3.0.1
```

I uninstall the wrong version to probably reveal a new error. I can just install it again later, I was thinking.

```
$ rbenv uninstall 3.0.1
```

It does reveal a new error:

```
$ bundle install
-bash: /Users/setoelka/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin/bundle: /Users/setoelka/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Ok, that's strange. I can just remove the `.gem` directory there.

```
$ rm -rf ~/.gem/
```

Now another new error:

```
$ bundle install
-bash: /Users/setoelka/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin/bundle: No such file or directory
```

It seems like my PATH variable is messed up. So I do:

```
$ gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.2.27
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.7.1 (2020-03-31 patchlevel 83) [x86_64-darwin20]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/setoelka/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/setoelka/.local/share/gem/ruby/2.7.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/setoelka/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/setoelka/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/setoelka/.local/share/gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/setoelka/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
     - ruby
     - x86_64-darwin-20
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/setoelka/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0
     - /Users/setoelka/.local/share/gem/ruby/2.7.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/setoelka/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/bin
     - /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.1.2/libexec
     - /Users/setoelka/opt/anaconda3/bin
     - /Users/setoelka/opt/anaconda3/condabin
     - /Users/setoelka/.cargo/bin
     - /Users/setoelka/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin
     - /Users/setoelka/.nvm/versions/node/v16.5.0/bin
     - /Users/setoelka/.rbenv/shims
     - /Users/setoelka/.rbenv/shims
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /Library/Apple/usr/bin
```

So, it's clear I missed something when checking out my `.bash_profile` file. That's the problem there:

```
     - /Users/setoelka/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/bin
```

That line was somehow buried under a plethora of settings inside my `.bash_profile`.

Comment: Cool! What worked for me was `rm -rf ~/.gem/` this command.
Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem

I needed to run

> bundle

to reinstall all my gems. then

> bundle exec rails c