# Your Ruby version is 2.6.8, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.6 error while enabling new architecture on react-native iOS

Tags: ios, ruby, react-native, homebrew

I have already gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74189532/your-ruby-version-is-2-6-8-but-your-gemfile-specified-2-7-5) post

I am facing this issue on my new `react-native` project version 0.71.1 while enabling the new architecture for `iOS`

I have done all the below steps

```
$ brew update
$ brew install ruby-build
$ brew install rbenv

$ rbenv install 2.7.6
$ rbenv global 2.7.6

echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

When I run `ruby --version` I get `ruby 2.7.6p219 (2022-04-12 revision c9c2245c0a) [x86_64-darwin22]` which is the correct ruby version required to enable new architecture on iOS

but when I run `bundle install && RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED=1 bundle exec pod install` I still get error saying

```
Your Ruby version is 2.6.10, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.6
```

[image]

What else am I missing?

I have also raised the [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/36002) in react native's GitHub repo. This might help in understanding in what I have already tried

Comment: have you tried accepted answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/74357983/18073270?

Comment: yup, still same issue

Comment: Please do not post images of plaintext as [they are not appropriate on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3784008). Please copy and paste plaintext into your question.

Comment: I wanted to show all the installation details

Comment: is there a hidden file named `.ruby-version` in your project folder?

Comment: yes and it has 2.7.6. It comes by default when you create a new react project and it is showing 2.7.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue by running `bundle install --redownload`. It Forces a redownload of all gems on the gemfile, assigning them to the new bundler

Comment: Worked for me as well. A big thanks to you!!!

Answer (score 0):

The Rbenv documentation can define a version file named `.ruby-version` inside your project folder. Perhaps you have this file with a specific version number inside.

This setting overrides your default ruby version.

Link to Rbenv-Repo: https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv

**Update**: After lots of suggestion, we came to the conclusion. The command `bundle install --redownload` updates the local bundler and everything is fine. :-)

Comment: I have correct version in .ruby-version. It is the default react-native project. I have not made any changes

Comment: where is your local `bundler` installed? Maybe there is a wrong reference? If the command is unknown `whereis bundler`

Comment: bundler: /usr/bin/bundler

Comment: try `rbenv exec gem install bundler` to reinstall bundler. Reference to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33439130/bundle-uses-wrong-ruby-version

Comment: same issue persist

Comment: I have also raised this issue in react native 's GitHub repo. Please check if you have time https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/36002

Comment: I am not very certain about package management under MacOS, but perhaps you've installed bundler as a system package. Therefore, your OS uses the system package.  Another Idea is to run the bundler over `rbenv exec bundler`. Can you check both ideas?

Comment: Tried it same issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251559/discussion-between-tobias-munch-and-pritish).

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `ruby` version in `GemFile` to `2.6.10` and then try it.

You'll find your GemFile in your project's root directory

[image]
[image]

Comment: I need that specific version of ruby to enable react native's new architecture. Also changing the ruby version can cause more unexpected bugs in the future