# Capistrano: sh: 1: bundle: not found

Tags: capistrano, bundler

```
executing "cd /home/user/app/current/releases/20130620184147 && bundle install --gemfile /home/user/app/current/releases/20130620184147/Gemfile --path /home/user/app/current/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development"

[out :: website.com] sh: 1: bundle: not found
```

I couldn't get this answer to work:
[Capistrano and Bundler problem - bundle: not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290465/capistrano-and-bundler-problem-bundle-not-found)

I'm using Ubuntu LTS 12.04.

Comment: Stupid question: did you install the bundler gem on your server? If so, how?

Comment: run this after you ssh in: sudo gem install bundler --no-ri --no-rdoc